# disable init.d script in systemd

Tags: debian, systemd, raspbian, init.d

I changed the init system from sysvinit to systemd on a raspbian installation. The install boots fine, but now starts lightdm on boot. I don't want it to do that.

I noticed `lightdm.service` is started on boot. Stopping the service with

`systemctl stop lightdm.service`

works fine.

`systemctl disable lightdm.service` should disable it, but gives me

`Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory`

`systemctl status lightdm.service` gives me

```
lightdm.service - LSB: Light Display Manager
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/lightdm)
      Active: inactive (dead) since Thu, 03 Jul 2014 09:33:00 +0000; 22min ago
     Process: 762 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/lightdm stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Process: 411 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/lightdm start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/lightdm.service
```

I'm assuming that lightdm is started from an init.d script rather than a systemd script, and `systemctl disable` doesn't work if the source is an init.d script. What should I do instead to disable lightdm starting at boot?

edit: More info

output of `$ ls -l /etc/systemd/system`:

```
total 20
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   42 Jul  3 09:04 dbus-fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant.service -> /lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   37 Jul  3 13:03 default.target -> /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  3 09:00 getty.target.wants
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  3 09:04 graphical.target.wants
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 11  2013 local-fs.target.wants
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  3 09:04 multi-user.target.wants
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 11  2013 sysinit.target.wants
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Mar 20  2013 syslog.service -> /lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service
```

output of `systemctl --all -t target`:

```
UNIT                LOAD   ACTIVE   SUB    JOB DESCRIPTION
all.target          error  inactive dead       all.target
basic.target        loaded active   active     Basic System
cryptsetup.target   loaded active   active     Encrypted Volumes
emergency.target    loaded inactive dead       Emergency Mode
final.target        loaded inactive dead       Final Step
getty.target        loaded active   active     Login Prompts
local-fs-pre.target loaded active   active     Local File Systems (Pre)
local-fs.target     loaded active   active     Local File Systems
multi-user.target   loaded active   active     Multi-User
network.target      loaded inactive dead       Network
nss-lookup.target   loaded inactive dead       Name Lookups
remote-fs.target    loaded active   active     Remote File Systems
rescue.target       loaded inactive dead       Rescue Mode
shutdown.target     loaded inactive dead       Shutdown
sockets.target      loaded active   active     Sockets
sound.target        loaded active   active     Sound Card
swap.target         loaded active   active     Swap
sysinit.target      loaded active   active     System Initialization
syslog.target       loaded active   active     Syslog
time-sync.target    loaded inactive dead       System Time Synchronized
umount.target       loaded inactive dead       Unmount All Filesystems
```

output of `ls -l /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/`:

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  3 09:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul  3 13:03 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   36 Oct 11  2013 remote-fs.target -> /lib/systemd/system/remote-fs.target
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Jul  3 09:04 rsync.service -> /lib/systemd/system/rsync.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Mar 20  2013 rsyslog.service -> /lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Jul  3 09:04 sudo.service -> /lib/systemd/system/sudo.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   42 Jul  3 09:04 wpa_supplicant.service -> /lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service
```

Comment: We don't consider RPi/raspian to be topical with the meaning of Server Fault. The enthusiast nature of the device is better suited to [unix.se], [su] or in the case of non unix related questions [raspberrypi.se].

Comment: Thanks. Odd question, where can I find the exact scopes of these different sites to read up on the exact scopes of each?

Comment: Yeah it's difficult, the [about] and [help] for each is a good place to start. We also have clarification of certain points on our meta in particular and relevant to you http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5586/are-raspberrypis-ever-on-topic-for-serverfault .

Comment: Hrm. While I disagree with that, I'm way too much of a newcomer here for that opinion to have any weight. At the same time, it is at least as much on topic on Unix & Linux I guess. I'll ask for a migration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try (as root):-

```
systemctl disable graphical.target
```

After a restart, you should be in `multi-user` mode as opposed to `graphical`.

If that fails, check what your default target is with:-

```
ls -l /lib/systemd/system/default.target
# or, depending on your distro
ls -l /etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

Note that the only difference in the paths is the top level directory - either `/lib` or `/etc`.

The above should be a soft link to `multi-user.target`.  If it points to `graphical.target` then change it using (as root):-

```
ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target /lib/systemd/system/default.target
# or
ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

depending on where the soft link was found in the previous `ls -l` command.

Reboot and hopefully your display manager won't start.

To see what targets you have,  run:-

```
systemctl --all -t target
```

Comment: possibly surprisingly, that still lands me in lightdm

Comment: Hmm.  Suprised too.  I've done a bit more digging - the problem is that I can only SSH to a VPS at the moment and haven't a 'graphical' system in front of me to check my thoughts!

Comment: I've edited, now that I've access to a real system.

Comment: Oddly, it's still starting lightdm, even though default.target in /etc/systemd/system/default.target is symlinked to /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target, and systemctl list-units ==type=target doesn't list graphical.target as active. I have the feeling it's because of the specific fallback init.d scripts present; I haven't found what's causing it yet, but my personal issue is veering away from being a useful general purpose question, and is becoming more of a "help me fix my problem" forum question. I'd be grateful for more help, but acknowledge it doesn't belong on stack exchange anymore.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely moving away from being a general purpose issue, but I've no problems with that.  I've Googled (that's deseperate!).  Does running `sudo raspi-config` give you the option to disable desktop at startup?

Comment: I think I got a step closer in finding out that systemctl status lightdm has WantedBy multi-user. I haven't found a lightdm.service file nor have I seen lightdm.service in any wanted directories yet. Still, there must be some reason systemd thinks multi-user wants to have lightdm.

Comment: Does `dpkg -L lightdm` show the `lightdm.service` file?

Comment: `dpkg -L lightdm | grep service` gives me nothing. Nor does `find / -name 'lightdm.service'` as root

Comment: I tried to move this to chat, but it was blocked by our firewall!  What about trying `sudo update-rc.d lightdm disable`

Comment: http://pastie.org/pastes/9354287 and something sort of close to success? lightdm doesnt start anymore. I would have expected (incorrectly?) that I would end up with a functioning terminal on booting, which I don't. I'm such a beginner that I don't know whether that's bad or good.

Comment: This is very odd - it seems that Raspbian is using a mixture of both `systemd` and older `rc.d init scripts` which makes things more of a challenge.  Did you try the `sudo raspi-config` command mentioned previously?

Comment: rasbian is sysvinit, but there is a systemd package available. I think the last systemd step is running the LBS initv scripts (of which I was oblivious to just now), which leads to the odd hybrid situation. raspi-config already has the "Console text console" version still enabled.

Comment: I found this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/boot-without-starting-x-server

Comment: after turning it off and on again, the last boot steps listed are `ssh[426] starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd` `ssh[627] stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd` `ssh[635] starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd` and it "hangs" from there with a blinking cursor (no prompt) at the first line below it. I can SSH in now without problems, and `ctrl-alt-f2` to a shell with no problem, but I expected the boot to end in a shell.

Comment: I found this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/boot-without-starting-x-server
 which is similar to what you've tried :-(
On any other system, disabling the X server leaves you with a text login.  If you can manage to login, check `/etc/inittab` (if you have one) and see what the default runlevel is.  If you can, try change it to 3 which normally means text consoles instead of X.

Comment: I see the default runlevel change resulted in a different boot order, but I still end with a shell that seems to be busy with something. It might still be wrong (well, it is), but it's workable for now (and I learned a lot).

Comment: The correct way is `systemctl set-default multi-user`

Answer (score 12):

> `systemctl disable` doesn't work if the source is an `init.d` script. What should I do instead to disable `lightdm` starting at boot?

Ironically, neither of the "official" ways of doing this have been mentioned in any answer so far.  So for completeness, here they are:

You "mask" the service:

```
systemctl mask lightdm.service
```

Or you create a unit file of your own as `/etc/systemd/system/lightdm.service` that then becomes a proper first-class systemd citizen that can be enabled and disabled with the `enable` and `disable` commands.  Unit files supersede `init.d` files of the same basename.  You can nick the [`lightdm.service`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~lightdm-team/lightdm/trunk/revision/1965#debian/lightdm.service) that was written by Debian people, if you like.  ☺

### Further reading

- Lennart Poettering (2011-03-02).  "[The three levels of "off"](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/three-levels-of-off)".  *systemd for administrators*.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable and disable init scripts with `update-rc.d` on Debian. Use `update-rc.d lightdm disable`.

The reason disabling graphical.target does not work is that lightdm has no knowledge of graphical.target. It is an init script and starts on all multi-user runlevels (2-5).