# Explanation of systemd startup

Tags: systemd, raspbian, init-script, sysvinit

Raspbian Jessie uses systemd and most system startup processes seem to be run from .service files. There are still a lot of SysV init entries. I gather from reading various articles that Debian 8 has support for both systems.

Can anyone explain which SysV init entries are still supported and which not? How does systemd call init entries? Does it ignore if corresponding .service is running?

I have found a partial answer in man systemd.service

> "If a service is requested under a certain name but no unit
>   configuration file is found, systemd looks for a SysV init script by
>   the same name (with the .service suffix removed) and dynamically
>   creates a service unit from that script."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone explain which SysV init entries are still supported and which not?

There isn't a list, and it depends from the script and how well-behaved, bug-free, and conformant to RedHat/LSB conventions it is.

> How does systemd call init entries? Does it ignore if corresponding .service is running?

It does, albeit it is the *presence* of the service unit file that matters, not whether it is active; and a secondary utility generates native systemd units on the fly that invoke the System V `rc` scripts.  systemd does not invoke them directly.

### Further reading

- [How does systemd use /etc/init.d scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132)
- [systemd and non-existant *.service files: Are they generic?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187220/5132)
- [disable init.d script in systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159335/5132)
- [Fsck script location](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236968/5132)
- [debian services not running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204075/5132)
- [Porting old sysvinit habits to systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233855/5132)